# Simple customization of matplotlib/pandas bar chart (labels, ticks, etc.)

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas

I am new to matplotlib and I am trying to use it within pandas to plot some simple charts. I have a DataFrame that contains two labels "score" and "person", derived from another DF.

```
df1 = DataFrame(df, columns=['score','person'])
```

Producing this output:

[image: table output]

I am trying to create a simple bar chart, to show each person in different color, and this is what I have thus far:

```
df1.plot(kind='bar', title='Ranking')
```

[image: bar chart]

How can I customize it so the chart shows the person names in the x axis with unique colors and remove the "frame" surrounding the figure? How can I make it a horizontal bar chart?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: i just want to say i love your drawing skill and would pay money to output my charts like that

Comment: @swyx: these are created by matplotlib feature: *[xkcd-style plots](http://matplotlib.org/xkcd/examples/showcase/xkcd.html)*, inspired in turn by [this question on Mathematica.SX](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11350/xkcd-style-graphs).

Comment: @ojdo thanks! I meant to clarify that a while ago

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I guess this will give you the idea:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'score':np.random.randn(6),
                   'person':[x*3 for x in list('ABCDEF')]})

ax = plt.subplot(111)
df.score.plot(ax=ax, kind='barh', color=list('rgbkym'), title='ranking')
ax.axis('off')
for i, x in enumerate(df.person):
    ax.text(0, i + .5, x, ha='right', fontsize='large')
```

for

```
  person  score
0    AAA   1.79
1    BBB   0.31
2    CCC  -0.52
3    DDD   1.59
4    EEE   0.59
5    FFF  -1.03
```

you will get:

[image: hbar]

Comment: Thank you. How would you rank the order and show the values for each bar? (i.e. 1.79 for AAA in the first position from top to bottom, DDD in second position, etc.?).

Comment: @LuisMiguel you can use `ax.text( x, y, string )` to add extra text to the plot at position (x, y). the order is the same as in the series/data-frame

Comment: @LuisMiguel this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19917587/matplotlib-advanced-bar-plot/19919397#19919397

Answer (score -2):

Check out the docs for [`pd.DataFrame.plot()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) for more info. You'll also definitely want to read up on [plotting with `matplotlib`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html) as well as the [`matplotlib` docs](http://matplotlib.org/api/index.html) themselves.

Getting a horizontal bar graph is easy, just use `kind='barh'.