# Value on top of a barplot in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I have a table in pandas df, which has avg_sp and count1 as columns. I plotted a bar graph grouped by ranges and I also added a for loop for the value on top.

```
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))
df2 = df.groupby(pd.cut(df['avg_sp'], range(0, 110,10))).sum()  ['count1'].plot(kind='bar')
plt.xlabel('avg_sp')
plt.ylabel('browse count')

for p in df2.patches:
    df2.annotate(str(p.get_height()), (p.get_x() * 1.005, p.get_height() * 1.005),rotation=90)
```

But I am not getting the right result, as shown below, it's getting mixed with x axis, is there any way to bring up the no.s a little?

[image]

[image]

i added the code which pirsquared suggested, but it is affecting only the top bar, and other remain same.

Comment: Do you mean like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25447700/annotate-bars-with-values-on-pandas-bar-plots?

Comment: @lanery i want the values to be tilt vertically

Comment: You can add the argument `rotation=90` to `ax.annotate`.

Comment: @lanery i added that,check my new plot, the no. as mixing with each other

Comment: @MaxU Can you please help me in this?

Comment: @piRSquared Can you please help me in this?

Comment: does it work with `rotation=0`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

consider the series `s`

```
s = pd.Series(np.random.randn(10000))
s.hist()
```

[image]

---

[from matplotlib docs](http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/barchart_demo.html)

```
def autolabel(rects):
    # attach some text labels
    for rect in rects:
        height = rect.get_height()
        ax.text(rect.get_x() + rect.get_width()/2., 1.05*height,
                '%d' % int(height),
                ha='center', va='bottom')

ax = s.hist()
for c in ax.containers:
    autolabel(c)
```

[image]

---

same solution with `ax.patches`

```
ax = s.hist()
for rect in ax.patches:
    height = rect.get_height()
    ax.text(rect.get_x() + rect.get_width()/2., 1.05*height,
            '%d' % int(height),
            ha='center', va='bottom')
```

[image]

---

[rotated labels docs](http://matplotlib.org/users/text_props.html)

```
ax = s.hist()
for rect in ax.patches:
    height = rect.get_height()
    ax.text(rect.get_x() + rect.get_width()/2., 1.05*height,
            '%d' % int(height),
            ha='center', va='bottom', rotation=90)
```

[image]

---

I messed with the height settings a bit to get it where I'd like

```
ax = s.hist()
for rect in ax.patches:
    height = rect.get_height()
    ax.text(rect.get_x() + rect.get_width()/2., 1.01*height+100,
            '%d' % int(height),
            ha='center', va='bottom', rotation=90)
```

[image]

Comment: and rotation = 90 would work on this too? by the way,, thanks

Comment: in my **barplot** the height change is not happening, its nearly touching the x axis, even after running your edited post,
only first bar is getting affected, remaining bars distance is still same

Comment: Try and run the same exact code to see if it works on the example I provided.  If it doesn't work, that implies there is a difference in the versions of your libraries or something else system related.  If it does work, that implies that you have a typo somewhere or that you have to take the height adjustment to more of an extreme like adding 200 instead of 100.

Comment: i used 200,300 and other combinations, but it is affecting only one bar! and not all the bars, i have added another snapshot of my plot after running your code

Comment: Notice that I'm adding in my last example. When just scaling with a multiplier, the very small numbers stay very small. That's why it looks like it only works for the right most bar. Because that's the largest and one that responds the most to a multiplier

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127901/discussion-between-s-ringne-and-pirsquared).