# How do I convert this csv data into a bar chart?

Tags: python, pandas, plot

Tour = Tour Name

Start = Available reservations at the start

End = Amount of reservations left

csv file columns:

```
ID     |   Tour   | Start | End

12345  |  Italy   |  100  | 80

13579  |  China   |  50   | 30

24680  |  France  |  50   | 30
```

I have this so far

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("items4.csv",sep=",").set_index('ID')

d = dict(zip(df.index,df.values.tolist()))

print(d)
{12345: ['Italy', 100, 80], 13579: ['China', 50, 30], 24680: ['France', 50, 30]} #This is the output
```

I want to make a bar chart that looks something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQaHU.jpg) with this given data.

Comment: Please see if [this](https://matplotlib.org/examples/api/barchart_demo.html) is helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, call `set_index` and `plot.bar`:

```
df

      ID    Tour  Start  End
0  12345   Italy    100   80
1  13579   China     50   30
2  24680  France     50   30

df.set_index('Tour')[['Start', 'End']].plot.bar()
plt.show()
```

---

[image]

If you're interested in *annotating* the bars too, take a look at [Annotate bars with values on Pandas bar plots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25447700/annotate-bars-with-values-on-pandas-bar-plots).

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this without set_index()

```
df.plot.bar(x = 'Tour', y = ['Start', 'End'])
```

[image]