# How to add count on top of bars in seaborn catplot?

Tags: python-3.x, seaborn

How can I add the count on top of each bar in the catplot?

```
sns.set(font_scale = 1.4)
g = sns.catplot(y = 'Count', 
            x = 'Family Type',
            data = ser,
                palette = 'colorblind',
                height = 4.2,
                aspect = 2,
            kind='bar', 
            legend = True)
plt.title('title',
          fontsize =  20)
g.set_xticklabels(rotation=45)
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Display count on top of seaborn barplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55104819/display-count-on-top-of-seaborn-barplot) , a solution with catplot is mentioned

Comment: It doesn't because neither ```patches``` nor ```containers``` are available. ```H:\>pip show pandas
Name: pandas
Version: 0.23.4```.   ```H:\>pip show seaborn
Name: seaborn
Version: 0.9.0```