# How to add labels to two overlaid bar plots showing value_counts in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, plot, label

I have two overlaid bar plots from binary column data.
I need to add the value_counts number as label to each bar of the plot.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'y_pred': y_pred, 'y_test': y_test})
df.y_test.value_counts().plot(kind='bar')
df.y_pred.value_counts().plot(kind='bar', width=0.3, color='r')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image: bar plot]

In [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25447700/annotate-bars-with-values-on-pandas-bar-plots) I found:

```
for p in ax.patches:
        ax.annotate(str(p.get_height()), (p.get_x() * 1.005, p.get_height() * 1.005))
```

but I did not understand how this would loop through the bars in my case.
Copy paste obviously did not work. the code with 'for loop' was executed without error messages but still showed the same plot without labels...

[image: plot]

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'y_pred': y_pred, 'y_test': y_test})
df.y_test.value_counts().plot(kind='bar')
df.y_pred.value_counts().plot(kind='bar', width=0.3, color='r')
for p in ax.patches:
    ax.annotate(str(p.get_height()), (p.get_x() * 1.005, p.get_height() * 1.005))

plt.legend()

plt.show()
```

Comment: I tried this method (as you can see in the edit) it just gave me the same plot without anotations or error message (labels do now show somehow)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass `ax` into the `plot` command:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
df.y_test.value_counts().plot(kind='bar', ax=ax)
df.y_pred.value_counts().plot(kind='bar', width=0.3, color='r', ax=ax)
for p in ax.patches:
    ax.annotate(str(p.get_height()), (p.get_x() * 1.005, p.get_height() * 1.005))

plt.legend()

plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Play with `get_width` a little to align the labels.

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much!