# Frequency in seaborn histograms

Tags: python, seaborn

I have a dataset of used cars. I have made a histogram plot for the count of cars by their age (in months).

```
sns.distplot(df['Age'],kde=False,bins=6)
```

And the plot looks something like this:

[image]

Is there any way I can depict the frequency values of each bin in the plot itself

PS: I know I can fetch the values using the numpy histogram function which is

```
np.histogram(df['Age'],bins=6)
```

Basically I want the plot to look somewhat like this I guess so:

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Annotate bars with values on Pandas bar plots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25447700/annotate-bars-with-values-on-pandas-bar-plots)

Comment: Does it work for seaborn as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this question was first answered, `sns.distplot` has been replaced by `sns.histplot` (and `sns.kdeplot`). Also, matplotlib now has a function to label bars.

## New answer: with `sns.histplot()` and `ax.bar_label`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

sns.set_style('darkgrid')
df = pd.DataFrame({'Age': np.random.triangular(1, 80, 80, 1000).astype(int)})
ax = sns.histplot(df['Age'], kde=False, bins=6)

ax.bar_label(ax.containers[0], color='crims

on')
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.histplot with labeled frequencies]

## Old answer: with `sns.distplot()` and manual annotations

You can iterate over the patches belonging to the ax, get their position and height, and use these to create annotations.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

sns.set_style()
df = pd.DataFrame({'Age': np.random.triangular(1, 80, 80, 1000).astype(np.int)})
ax = sns.distplot(df['Age'], kde=False, bins=6)

for p in ax.patches:
    ax.annotate(f'{p.get_height():.0f}\n',
                (p.get_x() + p.get_width() / 2, p.get_height()), ha='center', va='center', color='crimson')
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

Answer (score 1):

Using the seaborn library I was able to plot the frequency of the distribution using the **histplot** function by defining the optional parameter **stat** with the keyword **'probability'** which normalize your graph such that bar heights sum to 1.

```
sns.histplot(distribution, stat='probability')
```

For more details you can look up the **documentation** where they present **other keywords**:
https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.histplot.html

***Be aware that the number of bins will influence the frequency.***

Here is my data ploted with **5 bins**.

```
ax = sns.histplot(distribution, bins=5, color='skyblue', stat='probability')
ax.set(xlabel="tree height (5 bins)", ylabel='Frequency')
ax.set_title("stat='probability'")
ax.set_xlim(xmin=0, xmax=50)
ax.set_ylim(ymin=0, ymax=1)
```

[image]

Here is the **same data** ploted with **100 bins**

```
ax = sns.histplot(distribution, bins=100, color='skyblue', stat='probability')
ax.set(xlabel="tree height (100 bins)", ylabel='Frequency')
ax.set_title("stat='probability'")
ax.set_xlim(xmin=0, xmax=50)
ax.set_ylim(ymin=0, ymax=1)
```

[image]

Although it is the same data, the frequencies don't match between the two graphs.

**I would therefore advise to control how the bins are created using the *binwidth* and *binrange* parameters.**

```
ax = sns.histplot(distribution, binrange=(0,50), binwidth=5, color='skyblue', stat='probability')
ax.set(xlabel="tree height \n\n **binrange=(0,50)** \n **binwidth=5** ", ylabel='Frequency')
ax.set_title("stat='probability'")
ax.set_xlim(xmin=0, xmax=50)
ax.set_ylim(ymin=0, ymax=1)
```

[image]