# Percentage in axis y histogram Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the following Plot

[image: plot]

I need to add percentage inside the bars, it should be like this:

[image: target]

My code is the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sb

pkmn = pd.read_csv('data/Pokemon.csv')
pkmn.head()
order = pkmn['Generation'].value_counts().index
order
pkmngen = pkmn['Generation'].value_counts()

plt.figure(figsize=(6,4))
sb.countplot(data=pkmn, y='Generation', color = sb.color_palette()[4], order=order, )
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Use [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25447700/annotate-bars-with-values-on-pandas-bar-plots), using the `value_counts` from the original series with `Normalize=True` as your labels, and modify the label placement logic for a horizontal bar plot, instead of a regular bar plot.

Comment: Please provide us with the data so we can reproduce the example. Thank you

Comment: Thanks, here it's de datasheet [csv](https://easyupload.io/0pel7l)