# Calculation percentage and plot using pivot-table

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, pivot-table

I need to plot a percentage graphic with a pivot table in pandas do you have any ideas? how I can calculate the percentage? thanks for your orientation!

This the code that I have :

```
df.pivot_table(index='obito', values=['asma', 'cardiopatia','diabetes','doenca_renal','obesidade']).T.plot(kind ='bar' , stacked = True)
```

This part of the dataframe that I have:

```
{'nome_munic': {66: 'Ferraz de Vasconcelos',
  97: 'São Paulo',
  100: 'São José dos Campos',
  207: 'Mauá',
  249: 'Cajamar',
  258: 'Votuporanga',
  285: 'Ferraz de Vasconcelos',
  290: 'São Paulo',
  345: 'São Pedro',
  378: 'São Paulo'},
 'codigo_ibge': {66: 3515707,
  97: 3550308,
  100: 3549904,
  207: 3529401,
  249: 3509205,
  258: 3557105,
  285: 3515707,
  290: 3550308,
  345: 3550407,
  378: 3550308},
 'idade': {66: 86,
  97: 62,
  100: 58,
  207: 54,
  249: 62,
  258: 37,
  285: 54,
  290: 71,
  345: 79,
  378: 61},
 'sexo': {66: 0,
  97: 0,
  100: 0,
  207: 1,
  249: 0,
  258: 1,
  285: 0,
  290: 0,
  345: 0,
  378: 0},
 'obito': {66: 1,
  97: 0,
  100: 0,
  207: 1,
  249: 1,
  258: 1,
  285: 0,
  290: 1,
  345: 1,
  378: 0},
 'asma': {66: 0,
  97: 0,
  100: 0,
  207: 1,
  249: 0,
  258: 0,
  285: 0,
  290: 0,
  345: 0,
  378: 0},
 'cardiopatia': {66: 1,
  97: 0,
  100: 1,
  207: 1,
  249: 1,
  258: 0,
  285: 1,
  290: 1,
  345: 0,
  378: 0},
 'diabetes': {66: 1,
  97: 1,
  100: 0,
  207: 0,
  249: 1,
  258: 1,
  285: 0,
  290: 0,
  345: 1,
  378: 0},
 'doenca_hematologica': {66: 0,
  97: 0,
  100: 0,
  207: 0,
  249: 0,
  258: 0,
  285: 0,
  290: 0,
  345: 0,
  378: 0},
 'doenca_hepatica': {66: 0,
  97: 0,
  100: 0,
  207: 0,
  249: 0,
  258: 0,
  285: 0,
  290: 0,
  345: 0,
  378: 0},
 'doenca_neurologica': {66: 0,
  97: 0,
  100: 0,
  207: 0,
  249: 0,
  258: 0,
  285: 0,
  290: 1,
  345: 0,
  378: 0},
 'doenca_renal': {66: 0,
  97: 0,
  100: 0,
  207: 0,
  249: 0,
  258: 0,
  285: 0,
  290: 0,
  345: 0,
  378: 0},
 'imunodepressao': {66: 0,
  97: 0,
  100: 1,
  207: 0,
  249: 0,
  258: 0,
  285: 0,
  290: 0,
  345: 0,
  378: 0},
 'obesidade': {66: 0,
  97: 0,
  100: 0,
  207: 0,
  249: 1,
  258: 1,
  285: 0,
  290: 0,
  345: 0,
  378: 0},
 'outros_fatores_de_risco': {66: 0,
  97: 0,
  100: 1,
  207: 0,
  249: 0,
  258: 0,
  285: 0,
  290: 0,
  345: 0,
  378: 1},
 'pneumopatia': {66: 0,
  97: 1,
  100: 0,
  207: 0,
  249: 0,
  258: 0,
  285: 0,
  290: 0,
  345: 0,
  378: 0},
 'puerpera': {66: 0,
  97: 0,
  100: 0,
  207: 0,
  249: 0,
  258: 0,
  285: 0,
  290: 0,
  345: 0,
  378: 0},
 'sindrome_de_down': {66: 0,
  97: 0,
  100: 0,
  207: 0,
  249: 0,
  258: 0,
  285: 0,
  290: 0,
  345: 0,
  378: 0}}
```

[image]

Comment: So you want to have a pivot table or a bar chart with percentages? Your code is fine as is.

Comment: I want to plot a bar chart in percentage like above, I don't know how to add aggfunc to plot percentages bar chart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default aggfunc is `np.mean` however it doesn’t compute the average per column or something like that, it computes the average of cells. In short it’s for every case the number of `1` divided by the number of `1` + the number of `0`. This makes sense sometimes, but not for your data.

```
>>> df[['asma', 'cardiopatia','diabetes','doenca_renal','obesidade', 'obito']]
     asma  cardiopatia  diabetes  doenca_renal  obesidade  obito
66      0            1         1             0          0      1
97      0            0         1             0          0      0
100     0            1         0             0          0      0
207     1            1         0             0          0      1
249     0            1         1             0          1      1
258     0            0         1             0          1      1
285     0            1         0             0          0      0
290     0            1         0             0          0      1
345     0            0         1             0          0      1
378     0            0         0             0          0      0
>>> df.pivot_table(index='obito', values=['asma', 'cardiopatia','diabetes','doenca_renal','obesidade'])
           asma  cardiopatia  diabetes  doenca_renal  obesidade
obito                                                          
0      0.000000     0.500000  0.250000             0   0.000000
1      0.166667     0.666667  0.666667             0   0.333333
```

Instead you probably want to count the total of patients per cell, then divide by column totals:

```
>>> counts = df.pivot_table(index='obito', values=['asma', 'cardiopatia','diabetes','doenca_renal','obesidade'], aggfunc=np.sum)
>>> counts / counts.sum()
       asma  cardiopatia  diabetes  doenca_renal  obesidade
obito                                                      
0       0.0     0.333333       0.2           NaN        0.0
1       1.0     0.666667       0.8           NaN        1.0
```

Note how every column now sums to 1. `doenca_renal` is `NaN` because it has no patients at all in the sample, so the percentage is not defined. If you only want to plot the percentages that have `obito=1`, then you can do this:

```
>>> from matplotlib import ticker
>>> ax = (counts / counts.sum()).loc[1].plot.bar(rot=0)
>>> ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.PercentFormatter(xmax=1))
```

[image: figure with percentages]

If you want to annotate the percentages on the bar, see [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25447700/annotate-bars-with-values-on-pandas-bar-plots)