# How to (iteratively) write a string alongside the bars of a grouped bar plot in Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have coded a horizontal grouped bar plot using Python. My requirement is that I want to write the number associated with each bar alongside the bars. I have seen problems similar to this on the internet. But I am not sure how to carry out the task in my specific case where there are grouped bars. The following is my code:

[image]

```
# importing package
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
  
# create data
df = pd.DataFrame([['A', 10, 20, 10, 30], ['B', 20, 25, 15, 25], ['C', 12, 15, 19, 6],
                   ['D', 10, 29, 13, 19]],
                  columns=['Team', 'Round 1', 'Round 2', 'Round 3', 'Round 4'])
# view data
print(df)


  
# plot grouped bar chart
ax=df.plot.barh(x='Team',        
        stacked=False,
        log=True,
        title='Grouped Bar Graph with dataframe')
```

Answer (score 0):

The updates required is added here. Note that I have increased the figure size so you can see the numbers and moved the legend box outside the plot. At least a part of the solution is available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25447700/annotate-bars-with-values-on-pandas-bar-plots). If you have the newer version of matplotlib (3.4.2 or later), you can also use the `bar_label` feature

```
# importing package
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
  
# create data
df = pd.DataFrame([['A', 10, 20, 10, 30], ['B', 20, 25, 15, 25], ['C', 12, 15, 19, 6],
                   ['D', 10, 29, 13, 19]],
                  columns=['Team', 'Round 1', 'Round 2', 'Round 3', 'Round 4'])
# view data
print(df)
  
# plot grouped bar chart
ax=df.plot.barh(x='Team', stacked=False, figsize=(10,7), log = True,  
                title='Grouped Bar Graph with dataframe')

# Move legend outside the graph
ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.01, 1))

# Add labels
for p in ax.patches:
    ax.annotate(str(p.get_width()), (p.get_x() + p.get_width(), p.get_y()-0.075), xytext=(5, 10), textcoords='offset points')
```

Output

[image: Graph]

Comment: Hi, can you please help me with this question:

https://stackoverflow.com/q/72229250/19024581