# Convert a datetime list into date in Python

Tags: python, list, date, datetime

I have a datetime list and would like to convert it into a date using the following code:

```
dates = (datetime.strptime(ts, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') for ts in timestamps)
date_strings = [datetime.strftime(d, '%m-%d-%Y') for d in dates]
```

The datetime list looks like the following:

> [datetime.datetime(2016, 11, 21, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2016, 11,
> 22, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2016, 11, 23, 0, 0)]

I receive the following error message:

> TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not datetime.datetime

Comment: `timestamps` is already a list of `datetime` objects; or more precisely, *at least one object in that list* is a `datetime` object. You can't use `datetime.strptime()` (note the *`p`* in there) to parse them to `datetime` objects *again*.

Comment: Your  `for d in dates` list comprehension needlessly uses an unbound `datetime.strftime()` method; just call the method directly on the `datetime` instances.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It appears the values in your `timestamps` sequence are *not strings*; they are already `datetime` objects. You don't need to parse these any further. It is also possible you have a mix of strings and `datetime` objects; the exception you see is thrown because *at least one of the values* in `timestamps` is a `datetime` instance already.

Just call the [`datetime.strftime()` *method*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strftime) on all objects in `ts` to format them:

```
date_strings = [d.strftime('%m-%d-%Y') for d in timestamps]
```

Demo:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> timestamps = [datetime.datetime(2016, 11, 21, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2016, 11, 22, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2016, 11, 23, 0, 0)]
>>> [d.strftime('%m-%d-%Y') for d in timestamps]
['11-21-2016', '11-22-2016', '11-23-2016']
```

In the event that you have a *mix* of strings and `datetime` instances in `timestamps`, you'll have to do some extra processing:

```
def convert_as_needed(ts):
    try:
        # parse strings
        datetime.strptime(ts, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    except TypeError:
        # assume it is already a datetime object
        return ts

dates = map(convert_as_needed, timestamps)
date_strings = [d.strftime('%m-%d-%Y') for d in dates]
```

Comment: one more question. After the conversion how can I add a day to the date? Using datetime.timedelta(1) does not work because it is a string now. Is there a easy workaroung?

Comment: Add your timedelta *before* converting to a string. `(d + timedelta(days=1)).strftime('%m-%d-%Y')` would let you do both in one expression.

Comment: Thanks a lot that is what I was looking for