# Converting a NumPy array of strings to datetime

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array of strings, for example

```
import numpy as np
foo = np.array( [b'2014-04-05', b'2014-04-06', b'2014-04-07'] )
```

To check for the data type of the array, I print it with

```
print( foo.dtype )
```

which results in `|S10`. Obviously, it consists of strings of length 10. I want to convert it into NumPy's `datetime64` type.

More precisely, I want to change the data type of the array without looping through a for-loop and copying it element-wise into a new array (the real array is actually very large). Naive as I am, I thought the following might work:

```
[ np.datetime64(x) for x in foo ]
```

Spoiler: it does not. Printing the data type of the array results in the same output as before (i.e., `|S10`).

Is there a memory efficient way to *convert* the data type of the existing array without the necessity of *copying* everything to a new array?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `.astype`, with `copy=False` to avoid creating a copy:

```
foo = np.array( [b'2014-04-05', b'2014-04-06', b'2014-04-07'] )

foo = foo.astype('datetime64',copy=False)

>>> foo
array(['2014-04-05', '2014-04-06', '2014-04-07'], dtype='datetime64[D]')
```