# Panda/PyPlot Make X-Axis Line Appear

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

[image]

This is what I currently have. I want to add a black line for the x-axis where y = 0, if that makes sense? Right now, the bars look as if they're just floating in the air.

My Code:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(values, columns=sectors)

df2.plot(kind='bar')
plt.axis("tight")
```

Thanks

Edit: figured out how to remove x-axis labels

```
plt.xticks([])
```

Comment: Add a short representative example of your `df2`. In this case it should probably only have 3 or 4 columns, to keep your question succinct and readable.

Comment: Also have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33382619/plot-a-horizontal-line-using-matplotlib)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Solution

Use [`plt.axhline`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.axhline.html#matplotlib-pyplot-axhline):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df2 = pd.DataFrame([[19.6, 2.3, -5.8]], columns=['Real Estate', 'Industrials', 'Utilities'])

df2.plot(kind='bar')

# the c='k' kwarg sets the line's color to blac(k)
plt.axhline(0, c='k')

plt.xticks([])
plt.axis("tight")
```

Output:

[image]

## Change the appearance of the horizontal line

`axhline` supports all sorts of options. For a thinner, dashed line do:

```
# ls is short for linestyle, and lw is short for linewidth
plt.axhline(0, c='k', ls='--', lw=.5)
```

Output:

[image]