# Plotting category means in seaborn categorical plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I have a plot with qualitative variables on the x-axis, and vertical scattered points for each category using `sns.stripplot`. I would like to indicate the mean value for each category. Perhaps a short horizontal line at the mean y value for each category. How can I do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Plot a horizontal line using matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33382619/plot-a-horizontal-line-using-matplotlib)

Comment: Have you had a chance to try the solution in my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`matplotlib.pyplot.hlines`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hlines.html) with some bookkeeping of the widths and locations for the lines. Here is an example using the seaborn `tips` dataset

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
sns.stripplot(x="day", y="total_bill", data=tips)
labels = [e.get_text() for e in plt.gca().get_xticklabels()]
ticks = plt.gca().get_xticks()
w = 0.1
for day, idx in enumerate(labels):
    idx = labels.index(day)
    plt.hlines(tips[tips['day'] == day]['total_bill'].mean(), ticks[idx]-w, ticks[idx]+w)
plt.show()
```

[image]

---

#### Some Explanation

```
labels = [e.get_text() for e in plt.gca().get_xticklabels()]
```

Extracts the text from the ticklabels which are automatically generated by `sns.stripplot`, this is more useful than `tips['day'].unique()` because the order of the labels does not necessarily match the order returned from `tips['day'].unique`. This is because if the [`order`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.stripplot.html#seaborn.stripplot) argument is not specified the order will be

> [...] inferred from the the data objects.

```
plt.hlines(tips[tips['day'] == day]['total_bill'].mean(), ticks[idx]-w, ticks[idx]+w)
```

Draws horizontal lines of length `w*2` around the center of the 'strip' and at a height of the mean of the column `'total_bill'` where the `'day'` value of that row is equal to the current day.