# Plot data points on top of Histogram

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, histogram, seaborn

I have histogram as follows:

[image]

I have some more data points which I want to plot on top of histogram with some value.

For eg:

RMSE of point a = 0.99

RMSE of point b = 1.5

So this two points should come on histogram and each should have different color.

Edit:

Here's my code for plotting histogram:

```
bins = [0.6, 0.8, 1, 1.2, 1.4, 1.6, 1.8, 2, 2.2, 2.4]
plt.hist(rms, bins=bins, rwidth= 1.2)
plt.xlabel('RMSE')
plt.ylabel('count')

plt.show()
```

How can I add new data point stored in some variable to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Add vertical lines as markers at the points of interest.
- Also see [Plot a horizontal line using matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59040003/7758804) and [How to draw vertical lines on a given plot in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64035939/7758804)
- **Tested in `python 3.8.11`, `pandas 1.3.2`, `matplotlib 3.4.3`, `seaborn 0.11.2`**

### Imports and example data

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
```

### Plot

- This is plotted with `plt.hist`, but also works with `pandas.DataFrame.plot` and `seaborn.histplot`:

  - `tips.tip.plot(kind='hist', color='turquoise', ec='blue')`
  - `sns.histplot(data=tips, x='tip', bins=10, color='turquoise', ec='blue')`

```py
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 5))
plt.hist(x='tip', density=False, color='turquoise', ec='blue', data=tips)
plt.ylim(0, 80)
plt.xticks(range(11))

# add lines together
plt.vlines([2.6, 4.8], ymin=0, ymax=80, color='k', label='RMSE')

# add lines separately
plt.axvline(x=6, color='magenta', label='RMSE 1')
plt.axvline(x=8, color='gold', label='RMSE 2')

plt.legend()
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much