# How to plot horizontal lines (`hlines`) in a plot with category axis in `matplotlib.pyplot`?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

**TLDR: I can use `Axes.hlines(y, x1, x2)` to plot horizontal lines on numerical axes, how do I do it on categorical axes?**

My goal is to create horizontal lines, centered on category (string) values (e.g. 'a', ...) and extending 50% of the width between the categories on either side.

---

**More detail**

Consider the following 2 `pandas.Series`:

```py
import pandas as pd
s1 = pd.Series([2, 2.5, -1, 3], pd.Index([6, 8, 10, 12], name='left-x')) # number index
s2 = pd.Series([2, 2.5, -1, 3], pd.Index(list('abcd'), name='x-value')) # str index
```

I can plot both as a bar graph with `Axes.bar(x, y, width)`:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2)
ax[0].bar(s1.index + 0.1, s1.values, width=1.8, align='edge') # width as numeric value
ax[1].bar(s2.index, s2.values, width=0.9) # width as fraction of distance between categories
```

[image]

But I cannot plot `s2` as a hline graph with `Axes.hlines(y, x1, x2)`

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2)
ax[0].hlines(s1.values, s1.index, s1.index + 2)
ax[1].hlines(s2.values, ...) #<-- problem. s2.index is not numeric. What to do?
```

[image]

My goal is to create horizontal lines, centered on the index values ('a', ...) and extending 50% of the width between the categories on either side.

Comment: Internally, the categorical axis is represented as `0, 1, 2, 3`.  So e.g. `1-0.5` to `1+0.5` is centered around `b`.

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59040003/7758804) in the duplicate.

Comment: Many thanks @JohanC, that cleared things up!

Comment: I had actually seen that question you are linking to, @TrentonMcKinney. It does not use categorical data, but rather numerical data, for which I had already found a solution. My question is therefore not a duplicate.

Comment: Doesn't matter if the data is categorical: _Note that barplots are 0 indexed, regardless of the axis labels, so select xmin and xmax based on the bar index, not the tick label._ as also stated by @JohanC

Comment: `ax[1].get_xticklabels()`: `[Text(0, 0, 'a'), Text(1, 0, 'b'), Text(2, 0, 'c'), Text(3, 0, 'd')]` and `ax[0].get_xticklabels()`: `[Text(4.0, 0, '4'),
 Text(6.0, 0, '6'),
 Text(8.0, 0, '8'),
 Text(10.0, 0, '10'),
 Text(12.0, 0, '12'),
 Text(14.0, 0, '14'),
 Text(16.0, 0, '16')]`. As you can see, the locations in your mre are integers, as stated in the duplicate.

Comment: I'm sorry, I thought two questions are duplicates if they ask the same question. The linked question only mentions a numerical axis type, not a categorical axis, which is the whole point of my question and explicitly included in its title. I wasn't aware that question B is considered a duplicate of question A if a subsection of one of the (not-accepted) answers to A happens to mention something that gives a hint as to what the answer to B might be. 
            
Anyways thanks again @JohanC for pointing me in the right direction and giving me useful information that answered my question!

Comment: Questions that are "permutations" or "slightly differentiated" are often closed as duplicates to other questions that are considered canonical, especially if an existing answer covers the new question.