# Draw a horizontal line in a matplotlib graph

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

#### What I want to do

I want to draw a horizontal line in the graph shown below.

#### Code and its explanation

I have a dataframe `df` which has two columns. One is the `datetime` column which contains `datatime.datetime` type values and another is the `bgl` column which contains integer values.

I extract data between `2022/1/31` and `2022/2/6` from `df` and then store it in the dataframe `df_x`. `df_x` is converted into a list type and then used to draw a graph. So I think the unit of the x-axis might be `datetime.datetime` type.

When I use the `ax.text()` method, I specified the `X` position to be `datetime.datetime` type, which is correctly shown in the graph.

Now I want to draw a horizontal line in the graph, so I specified `datetime.datetime` type values for both `xmin` and `xmax`. When I run the code, however, an error has occurred like below:

```
builtins.ValueError: xmin must be a single scalar value, but got 2022-01-31 00:00:00
```

So my question is: How should I specify both `xmin` and `xmax` to draw a horizontal line?

My full code:

```
import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"datetime":dt_string,"bgl":valbgl})
df["bgl"] = df["bgl"].astype("int")

df_x = df[(df["datetime"] >= datetime.datetime(2022,1,31,0,0,0))&(df["datetime"] <= datetime.datetime(2022,2,6,23,59,59))]

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(14,5), tight_layout=True)
ax = fig.add_subplot()
ax.set_ylim((50,400))
ax.grid(True)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.DayLocator(bymonthday=None, interval=1, tz=None))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter("%m/%d"))
ax.text(datetime.datetime(2022,1,31,12,0,0),300,"STRING",fontsize=14) 

plt.axhline(xmin=datetime.datetime(2022,1,31,0,0,0),xmax=datetime.datetime(2022,2,6,23,59,59),y=200,color="RED") 

ax.plot(df_x["datetime"].tolist(),df_x["bgl"].tolist())
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image: my output graph]

Environment:

- Windows 10
- Python v3.10.2
- Matplotlib v3.5.1
- Pandas v1.4.0

Comment: Dear richardec, thank you for your correction.

Comment: You're welcome. You say your English isn't great, but I find it pretty good :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Plot a horizontal line using matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33382619/plot-a-horizontal-line-using-matplotlib) You can see the anweres here that suggest using `hlines()` instead of `axhline`, it will allow you to specify `xmin` and `xmax` values following the actual data values.

Comment: Dear Shaido, THANK YOU !! I can now successfully draw horizontal line on the graph.

Comment: @kazutaka: No problems, happy to help :)