# How to add overlapping fill_between bounds on a line plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, data-visualization

I have two data frames - one data frame consists of all metric values on a monthly basis, and another one consists of lower and upper bounds for a given period.

```py
import pandas as pd

# sample data
data1 = {'Metric_Month': [pd.Timestamp('2022-05-01 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2022-04-01 00:00:00'),
                          pd.Timestamp('2022-03-01 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2022-02-01 00:00:00'),
                          pd.Timestamp('2022-01-01 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2021-12-01 00:00:00'),
                          pd.Timestamp('2021-11-01 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2021-10-01 00:00:00'),
                          pd.Timestamp('2021-09-01 00:00:00')],
         'Metric_Value': [0.2876, 0.3002, 0.3169, 0.3137, 0.3022, 0.3071, 0.3122, 0.307, 0.3091]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)

data2 = {'start_date': [pd.Timestamp('2021-11-01 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2021-10-01 00:00:00')],
         'end_date': [pd.Timestamp('2022-05-01 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2022-04-01 00:00:00')],
         'lower_bound': [0.2954, 0.2991], 'upper_bound': [0.3221, 0.3206]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
```

Metric data frame:

```
Metric Month    Metric Value
2022-05-01  0.2876
2022-04-01  0.3002
2022-03-01  0.3169
2022-02-01  0.3137
2022-01-01  0.3022
2021-12-01  0.3071
2021-11-01  0.3122
2021-10-01  0.3070
2021-09-01  0.3091
```

Bounds data frame:

```
    start_date end_date    lower_bound upper_bound
   2021-11-01  2022-05-01  0.2954      0.3221
   2021-10-01  2022-04-01  0.2991      0.3206
```

My goal is to plot these (different but overlapping) lower and upper bounds on the same scatter plot of metric values.

My idea is to expand the data frame so that new dates are added in rows between the start and the end (included) dates as I want to do `fill_between` plots on this data set.

In our example a new data frame would look like this (`end_date` column can be removed):

```
start_date  end_date    lower_bound upper_bound
2021-11-01  2022-05-01  0.2954      0.3221
2021-12-01  2022-05-01  0.2954      0.3221
2022-01-01  2022-05-01  0.2954      0.3221
...
2022-05-01  2022-05-01  0.2954      0.3221
2021-10-01  2022-04-01  0.2991      0.3206
2021-11-01  2022-04-01  0.2991      0.3206
2021-12-01  2022-04-01  0.2991      0.3206
...
2022-04-01  2022-04-01  0.2991      0.3206
```

The final result should be a plot like this:

[image]

How to do this, and do I need to extend the bounds df in such a way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Given the data in the OP
- All of the date columns in both dataframe must be `datetime64[ns] Dtype`, which can be done with [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) if necessary.
- Plot `df1` with [`pandas.DataFrame.plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html).
- Use [`matplotlib.axes.Axes.hlines`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.hlines.html) and [`matplotlib.axes.Axes.fill_between`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.fill_between.html) to add horizontal lines and fill between the lines for each row in `df2`.

  - Use [`pandas.DataFrame.iterrows`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html) to iterate through each row of `df2`.
  - See [Plot a horizontal line on a given plot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59040003/7758804) for additional details about using `.hlines`.
  - Use the `alpha=` parameter with `.fill_between` to add transparency to the fill.
- There is no need to create an expanded DataFrame with bounds at each month.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# add a color column to df2
df2['color'] = ['yellow', 'green']

# plot df1
ax = df1.plot(x='Metric_Month', marker='o', figsize=(10, 8))

# iterate through each row of df2 to add horizontal lines and fill between
for i, d in df2.iterrows():
    ax.hlines(y=[d.lower_bound, d.upper_bound], xmin=d.start_date, xmax=d.end_date, colors=d.color, label=f'Index: {i}')
    ax.fill_between(x=[d.start_date, d.end_date], y1=d.lower_bound, y2=d.upper_bound, color=d.color, alpha=0.2)
ax.legend(loc='lower left')
plt.show()
```

[image]