# Why did plt.hline() show an extended long X axis than number of dates in the data? - matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, date-range, x-axis

I'm trying to replicate a plot example but ran into an issue with the x axis and date range. When the plt.hlines() is included, the range goes back to 1970. When removed, the date range is correct. What could be causing the issue?

```
import yfinance as yf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

AAPL = yf.download('AAPL', start = '2020-4-5', end = '2021-6-5',)

data = AAPL['Close']
mean = AAPL['Close'].mean()
std = AAPL['Close'].std()
min_value = min(data)
max_value = max(data)

plt.title("AAPL")
plt.ylim(min_value -20, max_value + 20)
plt.scatter(x=AAPL.index, y=AAPL['Close'])
plt.hlines(y=mean, xmin=0, xmax=len(data))  # If this line is Removed, the X axis works with Date Range.
plt.show()
```

[image: Example of Issue, plt.hline included]

[image: Correct Date Range, but no hline]

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59040003/7758804) in the duplicate shows how to add a horizontal line on a datetime axis.

Comment: The xaxis is a datetime axis, and 0 in min=0 corresponds to 1970. xmin and xmax in hlines, must be dates. So you can use xmin=AAPL.index.min() and xmax=AAPL.index.max().

Comment: The dataframe can be plotted directly with `AAPL.plot(y='Close', marker='.', figsize=(9, 6))`, and this type of continuous timeseries data should typically be a line plot, but you can add `marker=` if really needed. See [code and plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vne7b.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with:

```
plt.hlines(y=mean, xmin=0, xmax=len(data))  # If this line is Removed, the X axis works with Date Range.
```

Your data points has data between `start = '2020-4-5', end = '2021-6-5'`

But when you use the `hlines` (horizontal line), the `xmin` and `xmax` functions are the arguments not what you were assuming them to be.

https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hlines.html

- `xmin`, `xmax` refers to the respective beginning and end of each line. If scalars are provided, all lines will have same length.

**When you set the `xmax=len(data)`, you are asking for `len(data)` "units" to be shown on the x-axis.**

When you remove that `plt.hlines` in your code snippet, you are essentially asking matplotlib to automatically determine the x-axis range, that is why it worked.

Perhaps what you are looking for is to specify the date-range, e.g.

```
plt.xlim([datetime.date(2020, 4, 5), datetime.date(2021, 6, 5)])
```

---

Full example:

```
import datetime
import yfinance as yf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

AAPL = yf.download('AAPL', start = '2020-4-5', end = '2021-6-5',)

data = AAPL['Close']
mean = AAPL['Close'].mean()
std = AAPL['Close'].std()
min_value = min(data)
max_value = max(data)

plt.title("AAPL")
plt.ylim(min_value -20, max_value + 20)
plt.xlim([datetime.date(2020, 4, 5), datetime.date(2021, 6, 5)])
plt.scatter(x=AAPL.index, y=AAPL['Close'])
plt.show()
```

[image]