# Seaborn FacetGrid - How to get % instead count?

Tags: python, seaborn, cluster-computing

I'm tring to create a Clustering Situation, with KMeans.

This is how my datasets looks like:
[image: df]

With these dataset, I apply FacetGrid this way:

```
for c in data:
    grid= sns.FacetGrid(data, col='Clusters')
    grid.map(plt.hist,c)
    grid.set_xticklabels(rotation=90)
```

Output:
[image: output]
For all features.

This is working ok, but the FacetGrid only show **Feature Value X Count for each clusters**...
This information is not too relevant too me, since **all clusters have different 'len'.**

E.g Customer Age for Cluster 1 plot is very higher than Customer Age for Cluster 0, since Cluster 1 has more elements.

What I need:
I need a way to compare each column of the plot relative to its total.
E.g
[image: img]

I'd like to see:

[image: Expected Result]

For each cluster and each feature.

Is it possible?

Thank you.

Comment: instead of using `plt.hist`, write your own function: https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/axis_grids.html#using-custom-functions

Comment: You can use [`sns.distplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.distplot.html) or [`sns.histplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.histplot.html) with `stat='percent'`. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59040003/7758804) shows how to add a horizontal line to a FacetGrid (distplot). The question is asking for too many things, and lacks focus. The question should ask one thing.