# Annotate bars with values on Pandas (on Seaborn factorplot bar plot)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

I wrote some code to try and solve this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39477748/how-to-annotate-bars-with-values-on-pandas-on-seaborn-factorplot-bar-plot

I used part of the code that can be found here:
[matplotlib advanced bar plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19917587/matplotlib-advanced-bar-plot/19919397#19919397)

Why is the graph so small? The code just tells to grab the accuracies from Pandas dataframe .

[image]

The code:

```
sns.set(style="white")
g = sns.factorplot(x="Stages", y="Accuracy", hue="Dataset", data=df, saturation = 5, size=4, aspect=2, kind="bar",
              palette= myPalette, legend=False)

ax=g.ax
def annotateBars(row, ax=ax):
    if row['Accuracy'] < 20:
        color = 'white'
        vertalign = 'bottom'
        vertpad = 2
    else:
        color = 'black'
        vertalign = 'top'
        vertpad = -2

    ax.text(row.name, row['Accuracy'] + vertpad, "{:.1f}%".format(row['Accuracy']),
            zorder=10, rotation=90, color=color,
            horizontalalignment='center',
            verticalalignment=vertalign,
            fontsize=12, weight='heavy')

junk = df.apply(annotateBars, ax=ax, axis=1)
```

This is code to annotate each bar, but ...with Pandas and Matplotlib. The only problem is that I do not know how to change colors and group the "x axis" :(

```
    df = df.set_index('Stages')
    ax = df.plot.bar(title="Accuracy")
    ax.set_ylim(0, 120)
    for p in ax.patches:
        ax.annotate("%.2f" % p.get_height(), (p.get_x() + p.get_width() / 2., p.get_height()),
             ha='center', va='center', rotation=90, xytext=(0, 20), textcoords='offset points')  #vertical bars
```

[image]

Comment: the graph is so small b/c the annotation go so far out to the right. you're not providing `ax.annotate` with good x-values

Comment: How can I find the good values? I am using g.ax; just as you used: fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,3))

Comment: Look at `g.ax.get_xlim()` (the range of X values you should be using) and compare to `df.index` (the actual X values you are using)

Comment: Values I should be using: (-0.5, 5.5).  Values I am using: (0, 24).  But I have 24 accuracies. I cannot change that. So instead I changed (-0.5, 5.5) to (0, 24). The plot always become smaller. :( So "factorplot" is considering each group of 4 bars as 1 bar. :( I guess the only way to do it is with matplotlib. :(

Comment: And when I do: ax=g.ax.get_xlim(), I get: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'text'", 'occurred at index 0'

Comment: That's because you assigned the output of `get_xlim` to your `ax` variable. Don't do that. I stea write a function that annotates the bars as they are drawn and map that across a FacetGrid

Comment: I understand that I have to remove the "factorplot" function and use instead the "facetgrid" function + a function that annotates bars. right?

Comment: @Paul H This is the code to plot bars:                                                                                                          `df = df.set_index('Stages')`
`ax = df.plot.bar(title="Accuracy")`
`ax.set_ylim(0, 120)`
`for p in ax.patches:
        ax.annotate("%.2f" % p.get_height(), (p.get_x() + p.get_width() / 2., p.get_height()),
                    ha='center', va='center', xytext=(0, 10), textcoords='offset points')`

Comment: that's difficult to read in a comment. add it to your question

Comment: @Paul H Ok. It has been added and also the final graph.

Comment: seems like you loop through `ax.patches` would work with a factor plot.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
    #Seaborn --factorplot

    colors = ["windows blue", "orange red", "grey", "amber"]  
    myPalette = sns.xkcd_palette(colors) #envío "colors" a la función xkcd_palette

    sns.set(style="white") #fondo blanco
    g = sns.factorplot(x="Stages", y="Accuracy", hue="Dataset", data=df, saturation=5, size=4, aspect=3, kind="bar",
              palette= myPalette, legend=False) #se suprime la leyenda

    g.set(ylim=(0, 140)) 
    g.despine(right=False) 
    g.set_xlabels("") 
    g.set_ylabels("")  
    g.set_yticklabels("") 


   #Matplotlib --legend creation

     myLegend=plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(0., 1.2, 1., .102), prop ={'size':10}, loc=10, ncol=4,  #left, bottom, width, height
                title=r'TOTAL ACCURACY AND PER STAGE-RANDOM FOREST')                    
     myLegend.get_title().set_fontsize('24')



     #Matplotlib --anotación de barras

       ax=g.ax #annotate axis = seaborn axis
       def annotateBars(row, ax=ax): 
       for p in ax.patches:
             ax.annotate("%.2f" % p.get_height(), (p.get_x() + p.get_width() / 2., p.get_height()),
                 ha='center', va='center', fontsize=11, color='gray', rotation=90, xytext=(0, 20),
                 textcoords='offset points')  verticales


     plot = df.apply(annotateBars, ax=ax, axis=1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

##### This can now be plotted much more concisely

1. [`Axes.bar_label`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.bar_label.html) automatically labels bars <sup>[[since matplotlib 3.4]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68323374/13138364)</sup>

   ```
   for container in ax.containers:
       ax.bar_label(container)
   ```
2. [`Axes.legend`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.legend.html) includes `fontsize` and `title_fontsize` params <sup>[since matplotlib 3.0]</sup>

   ```
   ax.legend(fontsize=10, title='ACCURACY', title_fontsize=24)
   ```
3. Also note that `seaborn.factorplot` has been renamed to [`seaborn.catplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.catplot.html) <sup>[since seaborn 0.9]</sup>

---

##### Updated [`seaborn.catplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.catplot.html)

```
colors = ['xkcd:windows blue', 'xkcd:orange red', 'xkcd:grey', 'xkcd:amber']  
g = sns.catplot(x='Stages', y='Accuracy', hue='Dataset', data=df,
                kind='bar', height=4, aspect=3, palette=colors, legend=False)

# auto-label bars
for container in g.ax.containers:
    g.ax.bar_label(container, fmt='%.2f', padding=2, rotation=90)

# add legend with custom font sizes
ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(0, 1.2, 1, 0.102), loc=10, ncol=4, fontsize=10,
          title='TOTAL ACCURACY AND PER STAGE-RANDOM FOREST', title_fontsize=24)

# redecorate
g.despine(right=False)
g.set_xlabels('')
g.set_ylabels('')
g.ax.set_yticklabels([])
```

[image: updated catplot]

---

##### Updated [`DataFrame.plot.bar`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar.html)

```
ax = df.pivot('Stages', 'Dataset', 'Accuracy').plot.bar(legend=False)

# auto-label bars
for container in ax.containers:
    ax.bar_label(container, fmt='%.2f', padding=3, rotation=90, size='small')

# add legend with custom font sizes
ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(0, 1.1, 1, 0.102), loc=10, ncol=4, fontsize='small',
          title='TOTAL ACCURACY AND PER STAGE-RANDOM FOREST', title_fontsize='xx-large')

# redecorate
sns.despine(right=False)
ax.set_yticklabels([])
plt.xticks(rotation=0)
```

[image: updated dataframe plot]