# Displaying the Value of Each bin in a bar chart - Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am working to create a simple bar chart that displays the number of each of the 9 items listed in a visual format. The goal here is to give a high level summary of the numbers by just glancing at the chart.

With my current code I am able to create a simple bar chart but I would like to have the frequency for each bin printed on top of each bar. How would I proceed to do that.

Here is the code and the current output:

```
# Graphing the dataset findings

height = [a_counter, b_counter, c_counter, d_counter, e_counter, f_counter, g_counter, h_counter, i_counter]


#print (height)

label = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i']

#print (label)
def plot_bar_x():
    # this is for plotting purpose
    index = np.arange(len(label))
    plt.bar(index, height)
    plt.xlabel('Classes', fontsize=25)
    plt.ylabel('Frequency', fontsize=25)
    plt.xticks(index, label, fontsize=10, rotation=20)
    plt.title('Class Distribution for Current Network')
    plt.show()


plot_bar_x()
```

[image: output image for above code]

Comment: What do you mean by 'visual format'  and 'bin'? None of these aspects appear in your code.

Comment: Apologies, what I meant is having text on top of the bar for a saying "a=3468"

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39519609/annotate-bars-with-values-on-pandas-on-seaborn-factorplot-bar-plot?rq=1