# Horizontal barplot with annotations

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, kernel, anaconda

I was successfully running the code when apparently python kernel died and dies everytime I am running this code:
Is it something wrong with the code or the problem is deeper? I can run other notebooks without problems.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
%matplotlib inline
plt.rcParams['text.usetex'] = False



df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.uniform(size=37)*100, columns=['A'])

ax = plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))

plt.barh(df.index, df['A'], color='ForestGreen')
plt.yticks(df.index)


def annotateBars(row, ax=ax):
    if row['A'] < 20:
        color = 'black'
        horalign = 'right'
        horpad = 2
    else:
        color = 'white'
        horalign = 'right'
        horpad = -2

    ax.text(row.name, row['A'] + horpad, "{:.1f}%".format(row['A']),
         color=color,
            horizontalalignment=horalign,
            verticalalignment='center',
            fontsize=10)

junk = df.apply(annotateBars, ax=ax, axis=1)
```

Comment: Are there any errors you receive? and if you run the process with Task Manager up, is your computer handling the process okay?

Comment: Got the same issue when running your code, Kernel just dies... strange. However when defining the function at the beginning and assigning the junk variable before plotting everything runs fine.

Comment: @schlump This is extremely strange, I was able to run this code as it is now with junk at the bottom. I remember that last thing I changed was something in plt.barh() line but not sure what (cant revert back after kernel died).

Comment: Well okay.. seems like its an issue with the plotting... when adding plt.show() after plt.yticks() everything also runs fine... seems like the Kernel does not really likes running the code when the plot is still "open"

Comment: Well I did as you said and its not dying anymore but, wow the result is awful right now. There is huge blank space before the plot, what did I do wrong

Comment: Thats just because you yaxis is bigger than the list of your items. Adding       plt.ylim([0,len(df.index)])  limits the yaxis to the length of your dataframe.

Comment: somehow I cant reproduce it consistently, the kernel is dying every other try... I think it dies when the junk excercised, but not sure whats wrong with this one

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138350/discussion-between-alex-t-and-schlump).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe you should change the title of the question, because as for you it does not really matter why the Kernel dies. As far as I've understood you, the problem is:

Creating a horizontal bar chart with different bar colors and the values of each bar as an annotation.

Here is a solution using Seaborn:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np 
import pandas 

sns.set(style="darkgrid")
sns.set_color_codes("muted")

# Create example DataFrame
df = pandas.DataFrame(np.random.uniform(size=20)*100, columns=['A']) 

# Create list of colors based on a condition 
colors = ['red' if (x < 20) else 'green' for x in df['A']]

# Create barplot 
ax = sns.barplot(data=df.transpose(), palette=colors, orient='h')
# Annotate every single Bar with its value, based on it's width           
for p in ax.patches:
    width = p.get_width()
    plt.text(5+p.get_width(), p.get_y()+0.55*p.get_height(),
             '{:1.2f}'.format(width),
             ha='center', va='center')
```

Creates:

[image]

Update:
For also coloring the text:

```
for p in ax.patches:
    width = p.get_width()
    if width < 20:
        clr = 'red'
    else:
        clr = 'green'
    plt.text(5+p.get_width(), p.get_y()+0.55*p.get_height(),
             '{:1.2f}'.format(width),color=clr,
             ha='center', va='center')
```

Making the plot larger so the background also covers the annotations:

```
ax.set_xlim([0, max(df['A'])+10])
```

Comment: Right, this solves the problem, however I want to ask one more thing, is there any way to color the annotiations in same way as bars? I tried just adding `color=colors` but its not that simple.

Comment: Yeha colors is a list of strings, you set the annotations in a loop where you need to pass 1 value.

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: See the update, you need to pass 1 value to the color kwargs. Because you are setting the color for every single annotation in a loop. So color needs to be 'green' or 'red'... before we created a list of colors ['green','red']

Comment: Okay this works, btw do you know what type of the variable need to be provided as clr? Because I redoing this barplot with a dataframe that has three columns and now im annotating barplots with different columns than the barplots itself so cant use the p.width colors but need to convert that column into type that can be used as color of choice here.

Answer (score 1):

Great! I can write annotations on horizontal barplot.
Well, what can i do if i have more than one bars?
[seaborn horizontal barplot with annotation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9SzoU.png)

After many tries that worked on my code:

```
cnt=0
for p in ax.patches:
    width=p.get_width()
    if cnt%2==0:
        a=p.get_width()-5
        clr = 'purple'
    else:
        a=p.get_width()+5
        clr = 'blue'
    plt.text(a, 
    p.get_y()+0.55*p.get_height(),'{:1.2f}'.format(width),color=clr,ha='center', va='center')
    cnt=cnt+1
```

result is:

[image: annotated horizontal barplot]