# Jupyter Notebook: Putting the numbers on top of the Bar

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am new in Jupyer Notebook/Python. Can i ask what script should I add if I want my numbers, to be also placed on top of the bars? [image]

please see image below.

Comment: [Did you try this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28931224/adding-value-labels-on-a-matplotlib-bar-chart)? (I can't comment)

Comment: I also have another column which has 2 value (Yes/No) how do I create a legend to make my bars 2 colors to distinguish the yes/no values.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19917587/matplotlib-advanced-bar-plot/19919397#19919397) might help with different colors.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for something like this...
[image]

here is a sample code taken from [this site](https://web.archive.org/web/20170228011551/http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/barchart_demo.html)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N = 5
men_means = (20, 35, 30, 35, 27)
men_std = (2, 3, 4, 1, 2)

ind = np.arange(N)  # the x locations for the groups
width = 0.35       # the width of the bars

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
rects1 = ax.bar(ind, men_means, width, color='r', yerr=men_std)

women_means = (25, 32, 34, 20, 25)
women_std = (3, 5, 2, 3, 3)
rects2 = ax.bar(ind + width, women_means, width, color='y', yerr=women_std)

# add some text for labels, title and axes ticks
ax.set_ylabel('Scores')
ax.set_title('Scores by group and gender')
ax.set_xticks(ind + width / 2)
ax.set_xticklabels(('G1', 'G2', 'G3', 'G4', 'G5'))

ax.legend((rects1[0], rects2[0]), ('Men', 'Women'))


def autolabel(rects):
    """
    Attach a text label above each bar displaying its height
    """
    for rect in rects:
        height = rect.get_height()
        ax.text(rect.get_x() + rect.get_width()/2., 1.05*height,
                '%d' % int(height),
                ha='center', va='bottom')

autolabel(rects1)
autolabel(rects2)

plt.show()
```