# How to show a sign on top of bar plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to print an asterisks on top of certain bars (for example, bars with the biggest difference or by name). `ax.text` is the command I know, but I could not do what I wanted to do.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


group_A = {'a': 0.2939404171023072, 'b': 0.18718821401609165, 'c': 0.07680315854941605, 'd': 0.018221751437274128, 'e': 0.12271298549876533, 'f': 0.25195575250726593, 'g': 0.10341280474995126}
group_B = {'a': 0.3253155986361845, 'b': 0.21567173672424556, 'c': 0.11965759369697668, 'd': 0.010456735282581807, 'e': 0.10248715529720853, 'f': 0.22193945872515902, 'g': 0.11353246654852137}

X = np.arange(len(group_A))
ax = plt.subplot(111)
ax.bar(X, group_A.values(), width=0.2, color='r', align='center')
ax.bar(X - 0.2, group_B.values(), width=0.2, color='b', align='center')
ax.legend(('A', 'B'))
plt.xticks(X, group_A.keys())
plt.xticks(rotation="45")
plt.grid()

# Here
# ax.text(X, group_B.values(), '*', fontsize=12)

plt.show()
```

What I want is something like this:
[How to show a sign on top of bar plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0pOE0.png)

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19917587/matplotlib-advanced-bar-plot/19919397#19919397

Answer (score 2):

```
for x in [0,2,5]:
    ax.text(x, .95, '*', fontsize=12, transform=ax.get_xaxis_transform())
```

[`get_xaxis_transform`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.get_xaxis_transform.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.get_xaxis_transform) gets a transformation where x is in data coordinates and y in axis coodinates, so that the asterisks are at 95 % of axes height, not depending on the concrete bar heights.