# Add value labels to stacked bar chart

Tags: python, matplotlib, pivot, axis-labels, stacked-bar-chart

**Last update:** I figured it out by looking at a million different stackoverflow posts.

1. To turn off the scientific notation for tick labels, I added:
   `ax.ticklabel_format(useOffset=False,style='plain')`
   `ax.get_yaxis().set_major_formatter(matplotlib.ticket.FuncFormatter(lambda y, pos: f'{y:,.0f}'))`
2. To turn off the scientific notation for `bar_label`, I added:
   `for container in ax.containers:`
       `ax.bar_label(container,label_type="center",labels=[f'{x:,.0f}' for x in container.datavalues]`
3. To plot the bars as stacked instead of overlapping, I added:
   `p2=ax.bar(pivot.index,pivot['Unrecovered'], bottom=pivot['Paid'], label="Unrecovered")`

**2nd Update:** I upgraded `matplotlib` to version 3.5.1. As a result, the value labels are showing up but they are still in scientific notation.
See screenshot below
[image]
**Update:** Based on user's comments below, I read through the [bar_label demo](https://matplotlib.org/3.5.0/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/bar_label_demo.html) from matplotlib, which was super helpful, and re-wrote my python code to mimic the bar_label demo.

However, I've run into the following problems with my new code:

1. I'm still not getting value labels and getting an `AttributError: 'AxesSupplot' object has no attribute 'bar_label'`
2. It is not plotting `Paid`for `Fiscal Year = 2022`
3. Y-axis is using scientific notation and I want the `ax.set_ylim(0,10000000)`

See screenshot of my new code below[image]

**Can someone help me debug these issues? Thank you!**

### **Original Post question:**

I have a pivot table called `claims` where the index = 'fiscal years' and the values = {'Claim', 'Paid'}.

`pivot = claims.pivot_table(values={'Claim','Paid'}, index='Fiscal Year', aggfunc='sum')`
[image: claim.pivot_table]

I then added calculated values to the pivot table to show 'Unrecovered' and 'Recovered' where 'Recovered' is the percentage of 'Paid' divided by 'Claim'

`pivot['Unrecovered'] = pivot['Claim] - pivot['Paid']`
`pivot['Recovered'] = ((pivot['Paid] / pivot['Claim']) * 100)`
[image: Calculate recovered vs. unrecovered]

Using the pivot table, I created a stacked bar chart where `x = 'Fiscal year'` and `y = {'Paid' 'Unrecovered'}` and with secondary y-axis showing `% Recovered`

`ax = pivot.plot(y = ['Paid','Unrecovered'],kind='bar',rot=0,stacked = True,ylabel = "Amount ($)")`

Now I format the y-axis tick labels with commas
`ax.get_yaxis().set_major_formatter(matplotlib.ticker.FuncFormatter(lambda y, pos: f'{y:,.0f}'))`

And then I add line over stacked bar chart where `y ='Unrecovered'`

`ax1 = pivot.reset_index()["Recovered"].plot(secondary_y = True,color = 'k',marker = 'o')`
`ax1.set_ylabel("Recovered (%)") # adds a label to the second y-axis`
`ax1.set_ylim(0,100) # forces the y-axis to show 0 thru 100 instead of decimals`

This section below is where I have been trying to add value labels to the stacked bar chart using 'plt.annotate' but nothing actually appears in the chart

`for x,y in zip():label = '{:.0f}'.format(y)`
    `plt.annotate(label,(x,y), textcoords="offset points",xytext=(0,10),ha='center')`

`plt.show()`
[image: plot stacked bar chart]

I want to add value labels to the stacked bar chart showing the amount for each fiscal year in the center of the bars.

I have tried so many solutions but none seem to work for me. My latest attempt uses `plt.annotate` but nothing appears in the bar chart.

I will really appreciate if someone could help guide me through this!!

Comment: This seems promising: https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar_label.html

Comment: If that doesn't, here's an old answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19917587/matplotlib-advanced-bar-plot/19919397#19919397

Comment: Neither of those two links seems to fix my issue. I tried to use `ax.bar(left=pivot.index,height='Paid',align='center)` but I get an error message that says `bar() missing 1 required positional argument: 'x'` but nothing I try makes the error go away.

Comment: I also tried entering  `x='Fiscal Year'` but then I get an error message saying that `'Rectangle' object has no property 'left'`

Comment: "Paid" is a string labeling a column in your dataframe, but you didn't pass the dataframe to `ax.bar`.

Comment: I changed it to `ax['Paid']` and now I get a new error `TypeError: 'AxesSubplot' object is not subscriptable.`

Comment: `ax` is a Matplotlib object. Your data is in a pandas dataframe called `pivot`. There's no inherent relationship between the two.

Comment: ok. I'm not sure what to do with that info.

Comment: I recommend you read the Matplotlib docs on bar plots. Here's an official example which includes the use of `bar_label`: https://matplotlib.org/3.5.0/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/bar_label_demo.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-bar-label-demo-py

Comment: I have read through the `bar_label` demo from matplotlib which is super helpful. I re-wrote my python code to mimic the bar_label demo but I'm still getting an `AttributError: 'AxesSupplot' object has no attribute 'bar_label'`. I'll update my question with my latest attempt.

Comment: `bar_label` is pretty new. I bet you need to update your version of Matplotlib

Comment: my env is using `matplotlib version = 3.3.1`

Comment: I just upgraded `matplotlib_version ==3.5.1` and now the value labels are showing  but they are showing in scientific notation. Anyway to force the y-axis and value labels to display with formatting?

Comment: y-axis formatting is covered in a lot of question on this site

Comment: Ok. Do you think you can help me debug why `Paid` is overlapping `Unrecovered`?

Comment: I figured it out by searching other stackoverflow posts.